# HP Proliant DL380p Gen 8 with p420i raid controller attempting to install Centos 6 or 7

Tags: linux, centos, hp, usb-boot

I am attempting to install Centos 6 or 7 on a backup server Proliant DL380p Gen 8 with a p420i controller. The problem is when I use the intelligent provisioning built in to setup the raid and such, it only gives me 4 options to install Microsoft Windows, RedHat Linux, VMWare ESX, or VMWare custom image. Under each of those you can select `Disc`, `Network Share`, `FTP`, or `USB`. The problem is I want to install Centos, and when I select Redhat Linux it will only let me choose `Disc`, and then if I click next it says:

> "Please attach some optical or iLO media before continuing"

and USB is not an option under Redhat Linux install.

This is the screen:
[image].

If I choose the `VMWare custom` or `VMWare ESX` option, the USB option is available, and when I click next on that I can browse through my USB drive but it will not load the Centos ISO and allow me to continue.

I have tried just making a bootable usb with Centos and loading from the bios with no luck. I keep getting a screen that says

> "Attempting Boot from USB DriveKey (C:) Remove disks or other media.
>   Press any key to restart."

Also this server does not have a CD-ROM drive. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use Intelligent Provisioning to install Linux.

For the case of CentOS 6 or 7, just create your logical drives in the HP Smart Storage Administrator tool, then install Linux as normal.

ILO media is probably preferred here. USB can cause issues with SCSI enumeration if you don't install the MBR properly.